# How do I get rear-curtain sync on a Canon 5D classic with a Yongnuo YN-500EX?

Tags: flash, hotshoe-flash, yongnuo, second-curtain, canon-5d

I have a Canon 5D classic and a Yongnuo YN-500EX and I'd like to take rear curtain sync photos with it but I can't seem to make it work.

The flash has this function, I can turn it on and see it being on on the lcd. I've also went into custom functions and enabled 2nd curtain. I tried all sorts of things like resetting all the settings or wiggling the flash in the shoe, cleaning the contacts of the shoe, and can't get it to work.

Does anyone have any tips? The flash is brand new. I tried it with another one of the same kind, never worked.

Do I need a PC cord for rear curtain on 5D classic? are the contacts faulty?

Comment: Are you using E-TTL or Manual flash power settings?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your shutter speed is 1/30 second or slower most newer Canon EOS bodies will use first curtain sync regardless of what is selected in the menu of a compatible flash (or via the camera's menu itself if the camera has the capability of controlling the flash via the camera menu). I can find no mention of the requirement for a 1/30 second or slower shutter speed in the [*5D Instruction Manual*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/6/0900000316/01/EOS5DIM-EN.pdf), so it may or may not be applicable to your camera. It is specifically spelled out in the manuals for my 7D (introduced in 2009) and later camera models. It is not mentioned in the manuals for the 5D Mark II and 50D (introduced in 2008).

With your 5D the second curtain sync can be selected using custom function C.Fn-15 which is covered on page 155 of the *5D Instruction Manual*. Please note that you'll still get a metering preflash after you've pressed the shutter button but just before the curtain opens which may seem to you like it is a first curtain flash.

Comment: What they don't have is a statement in their respective manuals telling whether the 2nd curtain setting is overridden when the shutter speed is shorter than 1/30th second. That is what the reference to them in the above answer is discussing, not whether or not they have the flash control menu integrated into the camera menu. I also own both a 50D and a 5D Mark II.